# Generics method code not compiling on linux

Tags: java, linux, generics

I have this code:

```
import java.lang.*;

class Util {
    static <T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T> boolean arraysEqual(T[] x, V[] y)
    {
        if(x.length != y.length)
            return false;

        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i)
            if(!x[i].equals(y[i]))
                return false;

        return true;
    }
}


class GenericsMethod {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Integer nums1[] = {1,2,3,4};
        Integer nums2[] = {1,2,3,4};

        System.out.println(Util.arraysEqual(nums1, nums2));
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it gives me this error:

```
error: method arraysEqual in class Util cannot be applied to given types;
        System.out.println(Util.arraysEqual(nums1, nums2));
                               ^
  required: T[],V[]
  found: Integer[],Integer[]
  reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
    inferred: Integer
    upper bound(s): Comparable<Integer>
  where T,V are type-variables:
    T extends Comparable<T> declared in method <T,V>arraysEqual(T[],V[])
    V extends T declared in method <T,V>arraysEqual(T[],V[])
```

But this happens only on linux.

$ javac -version: javac 1.8.0_111

On Windows (same java version 1.8) it compiles and runs fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: The code you presented compiles fine for me (javac 1.8.0_121).  I can see ways in which the error you present might occur in a larger context, where there is another `Integer` or `Comparable` class from another package in scope, but if a source file containing just what you presented does not compile then I think your compiler is broken.

Comment: same here, just with 1.8.0_112

Comment: On the other hand, your implementation does not actually rely on type `T` being `Comparable` to anything, or on any particular relationship between types `T` and `V`.  Therefore, you could consider just removing the type parameter bounds on `Util.arraysEqual()`.

Comment: Indeed, I have other source files in that folder that define differently the Util class. I have moved the file to another folder and now it compiles. Interestingly, on windows I used the same first folder (the one with other source files) and it compiled. It's an exercise, so I have to use the parameter bounds.

Comment: maybe because Windows does not consider character case on filename, Linux does!

Comment: It's completely unnecessary to `import java.lang.*;`, and you shouldn't use import-on-demand anyway.